# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode: window.gtag = (arguments) => dataLayer.push(arguments);

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code:

```
class MetricGoogleGateway extends AMetricGateway{
    constructor(id, name, token) {
        super(id, name);
        this.token = token;
    }

    configure() {
        if(!window.dataLayer && !window.gtag)
        {
             window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
             window.gtag = (arguments) => dataLayer.push(arguments);
        }

        gtag('js', new Date());
        gtag('config', 'UA-113071675-1');
    }
}
```

When the file is loaded by the browser, I got the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected eval or arguments in strict mode

But if I I run the following lines in the chrome console, everything its ok:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.gtag = (arguments) => dataLayer.push(arguments);
window.gtag(1);
window.gtag(2);
console.log(window.dataLayer)
-> console.log result: [1,2]
```

**NOTE:**

I notice that if I changed the line:

```
window.gtag = (arguments) => dataLayer.push(arguments);
```

For the line:

```
window.gtag = function(arguments) { dataLayer.push(arguments) }
```

I get the same error

Comment: Use `window.gtag = (arg) => dataLayer.push(arg);` instead. 'strict' mode is particular about using the `arguments` identifier in a function. Any identifier other than `arguments` should resolve this `SyntaxError`

Comment: Because console is not in strict mode. If you run your code in the console like this it won't work : `(function(){"use strict"; /*put your code here*/})()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is inside a `class` body which runs in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) (as all your code should), unlike the snippet pasted into the console.

The names `arguments` and `eval` are special and forbidden as identifiers. Don't use them. Just write `args` instead, or even better something actually meanigful like `layer`.

```
window.gtag = (layer) => dataLayer.push(layer);
```